# How to create a macro that distributes values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

How do I create a macro that takes the value of week 33 (AG5) which is 24, and distributes it in a 10-week interval 13 weeks before it (basically weeks 11-20) in the row below it, as evenly as possible in integers?

[image: See example here]

Answer (score 0):

This is a distribution formula **without VBA**

Put the number to be distributed in cell **AG5** *(24)*.  Put the number of cells you want filled in cell **AG4** *(10)*

Pick some cell, say **AB6** and enter:

```
=ROUND(COLUMNS($A:A)/$AG$4*$AG$5,0)
```

In **AC6** enter:

```
 =IF(COLUMNS($A:B)<=$AG$4,ROUND(COLUMNS($A:B)/$AG$4*$AG$5,0)-SUM($AB6:AB6),"")
```

and copy across:

[image]

The formula does a decent job of distributing the number.  If you really need VBA, you could use a macro to paste the formula.

**EDIT#1:**

if VBA is required then try this small UDF:

Option Explicit

```
Public Function distribute(Amount As Long, CellCount As Long)
    Dim temp, i As Long, factor As Double
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, zum As Long
    ReDim temp(1 To 1, 1 To CellCount)
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    zum = 0

    For i = 1 To CellCount
        If i = 1 Then
            temp(1, i) = wf.Round(i / CellCount * Amount, 0)
            zum = temp(1, i)
        Else
            temp(1, i) = wf.Round(i / CellCount * Amount, 0) - zum
            zum = zum + temp(1, i)
        End If
    Next i
    distribute = temp
End Function
```

This UDF returns an **array**, so it should be array-entered unless you are using Excel 365.